# (block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking) error calling AzureBlobContainer.listBlobs

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have tried to list the contents of an azure blob container, but whenever I try to get the blob names it throws a blocking exception.

**ListBlobsMethod**

```
public PagedIterable<BlobItem> listContainerBlobs(String containerName, String path){
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClientLocal = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(this.connectionString)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient();
        return blobContainerClientLocal.listBlobsByHierarchy(path + "/");
    }
```

**Method that consumes ListBlobs**

```
public Flux<IconsResponseDTO> getIconsUrl() {
        List<IconsResponseDTO> response = new ArrayList<>();
        PagedIterable<BlobItem> container = azureStorage.listContainerBlobs("catalog-history", basePath);
        container.forEach(blobItem -> response.add(IconsResponseDTO.builder().link(blobItem.getName()).build()));
        return Flux.fromIterable(response).flatMap(icon -> Mono::just);
    }
```

What can I do in these cases?

I am trying to list the contents of an azublod container and display it in a list.